# Rails 3 :remote => true does not trigger AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<%= link_to "Exhibitions", :action => 'tabExhibitions', :id => @app.id, :remote => true %>
```

It generates:

```
<div class="tabbarButton" id="tabbarExhibitions">
    <a href="/apps/3/tabExhibitions?remote=true">Exhibitions</a>
</div>
```

Which results in a common GET request when clicked.

I am new to Rails but my understanding was that setting `:remote => true` should have created a `<a href="..." data-remote=true>` instead of a plain link.

I am using jQuery, the necessary headers and meta tags are in place. I should mention this project was upgraded from Rails 2.3.8

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`link_to` is putting `:remote => true` into the `url` portion of the argument list, and creating a query-string parameter for it (see the parameters [in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)). Essentially, what you've written is:

```
<%= link_to "Exhibitions", { :action => 'tabExhibitions', :id => @app.id, :remote => true } %>
```

You'll want to have a separate Hash for the `html_options`:

```
<%= link_to "Exhibitions", { :action => 'tabExhibitions', :id => @app.id }, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Thank you, the exact same thing was happening to me